# Why loss is NaN

Tags: python, nan

I am learning about DNN and transformers and I have the following problem. Running the model on IMDB dataset this transformer NN works just fine. But when I try and run it on another dataset which instead of 2 classes has 4, the loss goes to NaN and the accuracy quickly goes to 0. Please if you are kind to help me. I am struggling for 2 days with the same problem.

I've tried clipping gradients, increasing batch size, increasing dropout, reducing lr.
If you are kind to help me I will be forever grateful.

```
embed_dim = 32  # Embedding size for each token
num_heads = 2  # Number of attention heads
ff_dim = 32  # Hidden layer size in feed forward network inside transformer

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,))
embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)
x = embedding_layer(inputs)
transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim)
x = transformer_block(x)
# x = transformer_block(x)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)

x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-04,clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(
    x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_val, y_val)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running on GPU and the error did not appeared. It was because I was having labels [1,2,4,5] and I should have labels between 0 and 4.